# pppd, local and remote IP address are identical, no internet access

Tags: linux, networking

I am using a cell modem connected to an embedded linux platform and I'm setting up a data connection over the cell modem. Note that I had this working perfectly fine but I recently created a new system image and cannot get this to work. OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1, kernel 3.16.2 and pppd 2.4.5.

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the same IP address is being assigned to local and remote IP addresses, see syslog below:

```
Jun  1 11:11:30 arm pppd[2118]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun  1 11:11:31 arm pppd[2118]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -vV -f /etc/ppp/chat-HSPA910CF-nopin finished (pid 2127), status = 0x0
Jun  1 11:11:31 arm pppd[2118]: Serial connection established.
Jun  1 11:11:31 arm pppd[2118]: using channel 1
Jun  1 11:11:31 arm pppd[2118]: Using interface ppp0
Jun  1 11:11:31 arm pppd[2118]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/mux0
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x96a24aa4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x2dc7c3aa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: No auth is possible
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x2dc7c3aa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x96a24aa4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x96a24aa4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x2dc7c3aa]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x96a24aa4]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:32 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:33 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:33 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:34 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:34 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x5 <addr 100.120.34.72> <ms-dns1 209.91.107.11> <ms-dns2 209.121.225.11>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <addr 100.120.34.72> <ms-dns1 209.91.107.11> <ms-dns2 209.121.225.11>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 100.120.34.72>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2 <addr 100.120.34.72>]
Jun  1 11:11:35 arm pppd[2118]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x6 <addr 100.120.34.72> <ms-dns1 209.91.107.11> <ms-dns2 209.121.225.11>]
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: not replacing existing default route via 192.168.1.254
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: local  IP address 100.120.34.72
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: remote IP address 100.120.34.72
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: primary   DNS address 209.91.107.11
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: secondary DNS address 209.121.225.11
Jun  1 11:11:36 arm pppd[2118]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 2186)
Jun  1 11:11:50 arm pppd[2118]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 2186), status = 0x0
```

pppd peer file:

```
debug
#dump
linkname ppp0
#/dev/ttymxc0
/dev/mux0
115200
lock
#crtscts
#modem
nocrtscts
nocdtrcts
noauth
passive
usepeerdns
defaultroute
#noipdefault
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
asyncmap 0
#noccp
persist
holdoff 10
novj
connect '/usr/sbin/chat -vV -f /etc/ppp/chat-HSPA910CF-nopin'
```

chat script:

```
TIMEOUT 30
ABORT   '\nBUSY\r'
ABORT   '\nERROR\r'
ABORT   '\nNO ANSWER\r'
ABORT   '\nNO CARRIER\r'
ABORT   '\nNO DAILTONE\r'
ABORT   '\nRING\r\n\r\nRING\r'
''  AT
OK  AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","sp.telus.com"
TIMEOUT 30
OK  ATD*99***1#
CONNECT ""
```

The connection appears to work fine but trying to ping or access anything over it does not work. Could this be some setting on the modem side?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

The issues was not related to local and remote IP addresses being the same (although I still think this is strange (?)). The issue was realted to this line in syslog:

> not replacing existing default route via 192.168.1.254

For the time being I added replacedefaultroute option